# Javascript dataset for IE10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser, dataset, internet-explorer-10

I don't want to be replacing all the line of code in my script where I use the property "dataset" so that it works on IE10.

I haven't found a good polyfill that actually works so I can use the following line of code:

```
element.dataset.loaded = "yes"
```

Since most of my traffic to my website uses modern browsers, I just want to implement a workaround for IE10. Any ideas or tips?

Comment: Have you tried setting the data- attribute using setAttribute instead? `element.setAttribute('data-loaded', 'yes')`

Comment: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills#dataset-property-for-use-with-custom-data--attributes

Comment: I am trying not to go line by line and modify all the code to what you suggested, that would be my last option but thanks. 

@epascarello have you tried any of those polyfills suggested? I have tried a couple, some of them are from 2011, 2012 and seem not to work too well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What really worked for me is the poliyfill [html-dataset](https://github.com/adamancini/html5-dataset/blob/master/html5-dataset.js) available on github.
In case you are not using any framework (pure Javascript, html and css), just import via link in your html as following:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  ...
  <script src="https://github.com/adamancini/html5-dataset/blob/master/html5-dataset.js"></script>
  ...
</head>
<body>
  ...
</body>
</html>
```

In case you're using Angular or other framework, import it via polyfill,js (angular) or webpack. I tested on IE10 and worked perfectly.

In angular 9 I just download the file and include it in the project directory and just imported it.

```
import 'src/assets/polyfills/html5-dataset.js';
```

After serve / build the project it worked too.

Answer (score 0):

```
element.setAttribute("data-loaded", "yes")
```